# Deactivate or disable Controller/Gamepad functions for another process in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, game-development, gamepad

I am writing a little Windows Forms application in `C#` to detect if a XBox Controller is connected and if it does, it maps the gamepad buttons to specific keyboard keys (with SharpDX and InputSimulator). After that it starts a game where I want to use my own configuration. This all works great.

Unfortunately the game has built in controller support and always prioritizes its own button mapping and the problem is, that it only supports 3 buttons on the gamepad.

Now is the question if it is possible in C# to forbid, deactivate or disable the use of the gamepad for another process so it (that specific process) thinks there is no gamepad it can use?

I don't know if this helps, but the games I want to use my tool with, are made in `RPG Maker 2003` to make those games fully controller compatible. Maybe there is a way to just deactivate it in the game itself and I don't know how?

Comment: To be clear, the game does not allow you to _not_ configure a controller? If it's connected, it _will_ be active?

Comment: Yes, if it's connected, it will be active. You can decide if you want to use a gamepad (if its connected) or the keyboard.
If it's not connected, you have to use the keyboard. You can't configure any of the gamepad buttons. For example "A" on the gamepad will always be euqivalent to Space on the keyboard and "B" to Esc. That's why I want my tool to handle the button mapping. But in order to make that work, the game application has to "ignore" that there is a gamepad available.

Comment: Then you effectively are asking if there's a way for a third party application to completely block access to a device to any other application. I'm hard-pressed to expect that this is possible, simply because it would inherently lead to severe weaknesses to malware that simply capture all input devices and render any machine functionally inoperable.

Comment: That is what I feared but I figured I could atleast ask if this is possible. That's too bad. 
Do you have any other idea on how to approach this problem or is there no way that this will ever work?

Comment: This sounds like an issue created by the game developers. The best dirty workaround I can come up with is to find a driver that works for the controller but that the game does not recognize. In essence, test in which ways you can connect the controller to the computer _without_ the game recognizing it as an input device.

Comment: Alternatively, get an intermediary device, e.g. Raspberry Pi. Have it act like a controller emulator, and connect your controller to the Pi, not the computer running the game. Have the Pi connect to the computer and act as an input device.

Comment: Thank you for your Ideas. I will try them out and see what I can do.
Thank you for your time!